# A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'

Tags: angular, mongoose

I have const language array. i want all languages to be used as key of my schema object. i have dumbed my language array in constant and loop through it to get the value of each language and export it, now I am importing it to my schema and using it as key variable but I am getting above error
`language constant`

```
const languages = [
  "Albanian",
  "Amharic",
  "  Arabic ",
  "  Armenia",
  "  Azerbaij",
  "  Basque ",
  "  Belarusi",
  "  Bengali    ",
  "  Bosnian    ",
  "  Bulgaria",
  "  Catalan    ",
  "  Cebuano",
  "  Chinese",]

export function languageSelector() {
  for (let i = 0; i < languages.length - 1; i++) {
    return languages[i];
  }
}
```

`schema object`

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import { visibilityPlugin } from "./plugins/visibility";
import { languageSelector } from "./constant";

const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

export const TranscriptSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  [languageSelector]: [
    {
      startTime: {
        type: String,
      },
      endTime: {
        type: String,
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  confidenceLevel: {
    type: Number,
  },
  videoRef: {
    type: ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "videos",
  },
});
```

Comment: languageSelector is a function. Do you want a function as a key?

Comment: @TusharShahi no i want languages as key, for every language i want to create the same obj in schema

Comment: Then you will have to export languages and import the same. Which language should be your key in the collection or do you want all language to have different keys?

Comment: @TusharShahi i want all languages as key

Comment: Firstly your function will always return the first language "Albanian". It is not moving further than 0.

Comment: And do you want each language key to point to an array value or only object?

Comment: @TusharShahi i want all languages as key to have following array"[
    {
      startTime: {
        type: String,
      },
      endTime: {
        type: String,
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ]," as a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it is an error : You are passing a function as key.

Instead of using your function there :

1. export languages
2. import them in your file and loop through them.
3. add keys dynamically to the schemaObject.

Example :

```
let schemaObject = {
  confidenceLevel: {
    type: Number,
  },
  videoRef: {
    type: ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "videos",
  },
};

for (let i = 0; i < languages.length - 1; i++) {
    schemaObject[languages[i]] = [
    {
      startTime: {
        type: String,
      },
      endTime: {
        type: String,
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ];
}
```